# Why does including the TypoScript not work?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have my extension  `myproject_design`.

I then registered my TypoScript file in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides`:

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3') or die();

call_user_func(function()
{
    $extensionKey = 'myproject_design';

    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
        $extensionKey,
        'Configuration/TypoScript',
        'My Project Typoscript'
    );
});
```

This works, in the Template module in the backend, the template pops up. But when I include it, it does not affect the page in any way. My `myproject_design/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript` looks the following:

```
@import 'EXT:fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript'

page = PAGE
page {
    bodyTag = <body class="test">
}
```

Still, it does not make any impact. Does anyone have an idea, I am going insane.

Comment: Maybe you have some TypoScript in your database which overrides the TypoScript from your extension. And did you clear all caches?

Comment: "But when I include it, it does not affect the page in any way." You just showed the registration of the static and the content of that file. So the question is: How do you actually include it?

Comment: Have you checked with the BE module TypoScript browser to look after your TS ?
Have you checked the TS condition ?
FYI there is a shorter way to add class to body tag : page.bodyTagAdd = class="test"

Comment: Hey did you find your solution to it? Was it simply a caching-problem?

Comment: Hey @Kathara, if I remember correctly, I made a typo in the extension name.

Comment: @WhySoToxic thanks for your reply. I had a similar error. For me the problem was the extension key in composer.json which in typo3 11 created "incorrect" symlinks. Instead of `some_extension` it created the symlink under `some-extension` which of course caused trouble with the path to the files... (solved it just today too ;))